# Trouble printing a for loop in a page

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I'm currently trying to print the result of a for loop located in  a servlet onto a web page, however, for some reason, despite the for being correctly structured, it is only printing the first instance/result.

```
    private int[] tabla (String Numero){
               
        int[] resultado = new int [12];   
            for(int i = 0; i <= resultado.length; i++)
            {
  
                resultado[i]=Integer.parseInt(Numero)*i;
                
            }
    return resultado;
    }
```

What am I doing wrong? Is the for being interrupted for some reason?

Comment: If you put a `return` inside your `for` loop, it will execute the first time the loop iterates and return immediately.  So only the first iteration actually occurs.

Comment: I understand, thank you! Just edited the post with what I have now. Issue shifted to me getting a blank result on the page :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the = from the for loop
for(int i = 0; i < resultado.length; i++)

Comment: Omg it worked wth! why was the = causing it to return nothing?

Comment: array index is from 0 to length -1, so iterate up to length -1